# How to add add condition in mixin

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I have one mixin for width and height. Here is my code.

```
<div class="element" id="ele1">test</div>
<div class="element" id="ele2">test2</div>
<div class="element" id="ele3">test2</div>
@mixin size($width, $height: $width) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
#ele1 {
  @include size(80px);
}    
#ele2 {
  @include size(80px, 180px);
}
#ele3 {
  @include size(80px, auto);
}
.element{
  background:blue;
  margin:10px;
  color:#fff;
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
}
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/a4gLkqyp/8/)

in this code 3 elements are there one for third div I don't want to add height style then how can I add condition in this mixin. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add the height value conditionally in the mixin?

Comment: yes height and width both. there will be a condition if user just want to add height only

Comment: Added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS provides `@if`, `@else` and `@else if` operators for conditional styling.

```css
@mixin size($width: auto, $height: auto) {
  @if $width {
    width: $width;
  }
  @if height {
    height: $height;
  }
}

#ele1 {
  @include size($width: 80px);
}

#ele2 {
  @include size(80px, 180px);
}

#ele3 {
  @include size(80px, auto);
}

.element {
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" id="ele1">test</div>
<div class="element" id="ele2">test2</div>
<div class="element" id="ele3">test2</div>
```

Output:
[image: output]

Reference : [SASS Conditional Rendering](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if)

Comment: Tried your solution. Please check if anything missing https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/a4gLkqyp/26/

Comment: Updated my code as it had some errors previously. Please check now.